# Finding a string within an array with the same index of another array

Tags: arrays, function, indexof

example

```
arr 1 = ['apple', 'blueberry', 'cherry']
aar 2 = ['green', 'blue', 'red']

function findAlpha (Number) {

?? i want to use arr1.indexOf

}
```

So, i want to return the colour green when 'apple' is logged.

I want the index in arr 1 to input the value of the same array in arr 2.

so cherry is index 2 and so is red. I want to use that to give red as the answer to cherry.

And an if else function, so that if a fruit is named that isnt in arr 1 it logs 'we don't have that info.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not tell us which language you would work with. So, with javascript:

First, get the index of what you type in first array :

```
idx = arr1.indexOf(someWord);
```

second, if idx is equal to minus 1 say it is not good otherwise give the value of array 2 with the same index :

```
if (idx < 0) 
{
    console.log("We don't have info for that value");
}
else
{
    console.log("value for", someValue, " is ", arr2[idx]);
}
```

Hope it helps.